# Как отцентрировать картинки любого размера по вертикали и горизонтали в строке?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap, изображения

Есть сетка с картинками в 4 столбиках. Мучаюсь над тем, чтобы отцентрировать картинки по вертикальному и горизонтальному центру на любом разрешении вне зависимости от размеров картинки (высоты). Как это сделать используя только стили, не скрипты и не используя `flex`, т.к. нужна кроссбраузерность ie9+?
[Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/mt6tv6xu/)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: по вертикали - 1 изображение по центру экрана или какого-то блока?

Comment: @Elena Semenchenko каждое изображение по вертикальному и горизонтальному центру каждого блока - в ответе ниже именно такое решение и демонстрируется

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, можно превратить колонки в ячейки таблицы.

Но блоки, вышедшие за границу 12-колоночной сетки, перестанут [переноситься на следующую строку](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping). Поэтому каждые четыре 3-колоночных блока придётся завернуть в отдельный ряд.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/9jjcn6fd/

```css
.centered > .row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.centered > .row > div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container centered">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ух ты, как красиво и изящно - спасибо! у меня до этого получалось только с заданием определенной высоты

Answer (score -2):

`background-size:cover` в помощь

Comment: не уловил - поясните, продемонстрируйте как он отцентрирует картинку по центру

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?